# Resultset skips columns

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I am developing a software in Java, what I am doing is searching a value in full sqlite database (55 Columns and 1000 rows) and updating it.

I can find that value in the database but when I am try to update it I want to skip columns which have only NULL values. Using `ResultSet` it  automatically skips other columns which have non-null values.

How can I check if `ResultSet` is not skipping the columns, finding the desired column and updating that value?

What I tried is:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>() ;
rs = statement.executeQuery(); // that is the select statement 
//Select * FROM table_name WHERE column1 like %VALUE%' OR column2 like %VALUE% and other columns like this too...
List<String> cols = Arrays.asList(getColLabels());
// I am getting Column Labels from ResultSetMetaData and it works fine  
while(rs.next()){
    for(String column: cols){
        String value;               
        if(rs.getBoolean(column)){      
    //That is the problematic area, if ResultSet finds a column with full of NULL values it skips to next column.
    // But other columns it skips too , which have not null Values and after that ResultSet does not find a proper column.

            if((value = rs.getObject(column).toString()).matches(".*"+searchedVal+".*") ){
        //searchedVal is searched value 
                arr.add("UPDATE Table_Name SET "+column+" ='"+newValue+"' WHERE "+ column+" ='" +value+"';"  );
                // then send array in another function to update to database
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, 
rs.getBoolean does not work with different type of column types, so I changed getObject function.
Working code is:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>() ;
rs = statement.executeQuery(); // that is the select statement 
//Select * FROM table_name WHERE column1 like %VALUE%' OR column2 like %VALUE% and other columns like this too...
List<String> cols = Arrays.asList(getColLabels());
// I am getting Column Labels from ResultSetMetaData and it works fine  
while(rs.next()){
    for(String column: cols){
        String value;               
        if(rs.getObject(column) != null){    

            if((value = rs.getObject(column).toString()).matches(".*"+searchedVal+".*") ){
        //searchedVal is searched value 
                arr.add("UPDATE Table_Name SET "+column+" ='"+newValue+"' WHERE "+ column+" ='" +value+"';"  );
                // then send array in another function to update to database
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to solve the `problematic area` with the data tier(SQL command), not the business trie(java code).

You want to have rows which all of the columns must be non null? so simply add more condition clauses(`not null`) to your sql command

something like:

```
Select * FROM table_name WHERE column1 like %VALUE%' OR column2 like %VALUE% and column_n like %VALUE% and (column1 not null and column2 not null and column_n not null)
```